# Heroku Build Successful but application error in React/Node app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I'm running a React.js/Node.js application on heroku. I have been successfully deploying for a while but after changing the code base yesterday The build is successful and  I get an application error. Specigically what I changed in the code base was switching back from SASS to CSS na dadding OAuth to my nodemailer functionality.

I have checked all the environment variables and my port is set to `process.env.PORT || 8080`

```
2020-04-23T18:00:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mlisonek98@gmail.com
2020-04-23T18:01:29.044301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-23T18:01:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-04-23T18:01:28.310226+00:00 app[api]: Release v109 created by user mlisonek98@gmail.com
2020-04-23T18:01:28.310226+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8bb6c992 by user mlisonek98@gmail.com
2020-04-23T18:01:36.276828+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-23T18:01:36.276853+00:00 app[web.1]: > badgrey@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-23T18:01:36.276854+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
2020-04-23T18:01:36.276854+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-23T18:01:36.971835+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-23T18:02:34.074965+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-23T18:02:35.428955+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=badgrey-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=a08398b4-fa84-4b9c-9365-af9a5f357652 fwd="108.46.200.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-23T18:02:35.774613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=badgrey-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=d6bea10e-304f-4b1b-be04-33815ffb6c26 fwd="108.46.200.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-23T18:02:37.499473+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=badgrey-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=405f4943-a154-47d4-8bb5-0699597e8649 fwd="108.46.200.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I get an h10 error, and there is no other information. This application is running on the heroku free tier. Any suggestions as to why this is happeneing? I would be glad to upoad more code but I'm not sure what I would, especially since everything works locally.

Answer (score 0):

It was the node version, Node released version 14 yesterday or something.